# Creating SQL Database Table in C# using the existing Model class

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, model, model-view

I already have modelling classes for the tables for my sqlite database.

I would like to use the same classes to create tables on the SQL localhost server.

Is it possible to do it "automatically"? Or do I need to run the SQL command by inserting all manually?

In SQLite I was doing something like:

```
connection.CreateTable<Product>();
```

Is there a similar way of doing it in MSSQL?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Enable-Migrations command to install migration tool in VS package manager. when migration folder was created in your solutions just type :
add-migration yourMigrationClassName 
in VS package manager then you can use SQL_Query,LinQ to CRUD Or Change Tables by opening the yourMigrationClassName.cs and write your code in the Up Method.
use this link for more details:
http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-based-migration-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: Weocome to Stack Overflow. When adding to external source, try to add the relevant info into the answer, to avoid broken links in the future.